# Who owns the Family Sharing purchases?

Tags: ios-appstore, family-sharing

I have Family sharing turned on with another person, and the person is the "organiser".

If I buy an app on the app store, that person is the one who gets billed, but which account owns the application, if we cancel the plan? Is it on my account, as I was the one who bought it, or is it on the other person's account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201079):

> When you set up purchase sharing, one adult in the family—the family organizer—agrees to pay for any purchases that family members make while they're part of the family group.
>
> After it's paid for, a purchased item is added to the account of the family member who made the purchase. If you turn off purchase sharing, **each member keeps their purchases**, even though they were paid for by the family organizer.

So while the Organizer is the one who agrees to pay for the app, the 'owner' of the app is the Apple ID who made the purchase.

Comment: Awesome, it is something at least. Would be better if there was a possibility to choose who pays for what, but this will do. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Ravonrip That feature is likely never going to be included, as a way of dissuading non-families from using the service.