# Implications of changing who pays for family sharing

Tags: family-sharing

My Apple Family includes 3 Apple IDs

```
Apple ID | Role
---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
Alice    | Organizer
Bob      | Has a payment method added and is responsible for paying purchases
         | but doesnt have any device. Essentially a ghost account.
Charlie  | Adult in a Family
```

Now I want to remove Bob from the Family, add Bob's card to Alice and end up with

```
Apple ID | Role
---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
Alice    | Organizer; pays for stuff
Charlie  | Adult in a Family
```

The services our family uses is Apple Music, iCloud storage with couple purchased apps.

When I tried to change the person who is billed from Bob to Alice, I got a warning that the purchases will be lost and I wont be able to share purchases with other accounts for 90 days. I do not completely understand the implications of this change. Can someone please elaborate on this? Is the action reversible? Do we lose purchased apps, but keep all iCloud/Apple Music data?

According to this answer [the person who purchased (not necessarily paid for) keeps the apps](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/339981/216522), so if Alice made all the purchases (paid for by Bob) I think it should be safe operation, but wanted to double check first.